# Open Google Maps navigation directions with both coordinates and address

Tags: android, google-maps

We open Google Maps navigation we use lat/long coordinates. The problem is that the address isn't displayed correctly because it's calculated by Google Maps based on the coordinates. I can't find any way to provide the address, which we already have, alongside the coordinates.

The coordinates are actually based on a Google Maps search itself, but when the coordinates are converted back to an address in Google Maps a different address is displayed.

This code snippet is coming from a Flutter app but it should still be pretty self-explanatory.

```dart
final intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'action_view',
  data:
      'google.navigation:q=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}&mode=d',
  package: 'com.google.android.apps.maps',
);
```

The destination is:

```json
{
    "lat": 35.6533691,
    "lng": 139.7694851,
    "address": "5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan",
    "name": "FamilyMart"
}
```

The [Google Maps Intents for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) documentation doesn't offer any extra help. It says that you can only provide either address or coordinates, and neither one really works correctly for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly a few years ago, it was possible to set an random name for the location. It doesn't work now, but it makes sense: otherwise, the user can be misled by showing him some address in the input fields, and navigate by completely different coordinates. You are right: for random place conversion lat/lng to address and vice versa can lead to wrong result, but seems for named, widely known places like 'FamilyMart' (it shown as "default" POI on Google Maps) conversion is pretty accurate. Try to use "full" address: not only address value from line `"address": "5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan",` but place name from line `"name": "FamilyMart"` concatenated with it. Something like that:

```
"FamilyMart, 5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan"
```

and try to launch navigation mode via "classical" intent this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("google.navigation:mode=d&q="+Uri.encode("FamilyMart, 5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan")));
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
final intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'action_view',
  data:
      'google.navigation:q=${FULL_ADDRESS}&mode=d',
  package: 'com.google.android.apps.maps',
);
```

If it not works your way is either to navigate by coordinates (without a beautiful caption of the location name), or to write your own fragment, similar to the standard Google Maps.

Also, you can allow user to launch Navigation Directions manually from Google Maps application called by intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("geo:35.6533691+139.7694851?z=19&q="+Uri.encode("FamilyMart, 5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan")));
startActivity(intent);
```

It set map centered to `"FamilyMart, 5-1 Toyomicho, Chuo City, Tokyo 104-0055, Japan"` that found on map visible on screen at zoom level 19 near with center at`(35.6533691,139.7694851)` lat/lng coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. It's not perfect but I think it works well. My current logic will be to use name & address if I have both values, otherwise I use the coordinates.

Comment: @GuyKogus You're welcome! Anyway, seems there are no other ways now with Intents.

Answer (score -1):

```
String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude + " (" + yourLocationName + ")";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This doesn't open navigation directions.